# getAttribute not returning complete value for style in selenium

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, getattribute

I am using the selenium getAttribute("style") method on the following id element:-

```
<div id="ntsDiv_1" style="width: 250px; text-align: left; white-space: normal; top: 1090px; left: 131px; visibility: hidden;" class="mlt-pop-container">
```

but the API is returning only the half of the value. It is returning `width: 250px; text-align: left; white-space: normal;` and the remaning portion of the style is clipped.

I'm trying to extract the value of the visibility, but the method is not returning the complete value of style. Hence, i am unable to determine the correct value of visibility.

I executed `System.out.println("Style is:- "+super.getElement(NEXTAG_STORES_DIV).getAttribute("style"));`

NEXTAG_STORES_DIV corresponds to the xpath of the id element, and `super.getElement` extracts element by xpath

Please help me out!!

Comment: Well what version of Selenium? What browser? What language is this in?

Comment: using Junit, firefox, version i don't know

Comment: Hadn't you better find out? What version of Firefox?

Comment: firefox 17.0, dunno how to find selenium version, googled but couldn't find

Comment: Well the JAR's you are using, what are they called? They'll be in the format of `selenium-java-version.jar`.

Comment: let me try to locate it,

Comment: Where to find this jar, i am unable to locate it

Comment: please don't downVote this question, else i'll be barred from asking questions. Please answer this query instead

Comment: Did you not set up this machine? You would have referenced the jar's in your IDE (Eclipse or whatever you are using maybe). I cannot see your screen.

Comment: No, i didn't set it up. It was preconfigured for me

Comment: ok checked it, version is 2.25.0

Comment: please help me , i have told you the version

Comment: You need to update Selenium. Version 2.25 is about 7 months out of date.

Comment: ok. please remove the downVote you casted here on this question. Please, Please !

Comment: i am afraid if i can update it, i am using official system :(

Comment: you kindly remove the downvote please.

Comment: I didn't downvote the question??? Updating Selenium may not solve the problem, but at the very least you should try to use the latest version to see if your issue has been known and fixed in a later version.

Comment: thanks for upvoting it. I fear i cannot update my selenium. will have to look for some workaround :(

Comment: If you just want to check the visibility of an element, try calling `isDisplayed()` on it, rather than checking through the style attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tried this with Selenium 2.30.0 and it works fine, the whole attribute is returned.

Try the following things (all the examples assume `element` is the `WebElement` you need to test):

1. Make *really* sure only a part of the attribute is returned. Aren't you just printing it into console? Many consoles have a limited line length. Try setting your console to show long lines. Check programatically the length of the returned value, or try evaluating

   ```java
   element.getAttribute("style").contains("visibility")
   ```
2. Try upgrading your Selenium library, if you can. I am not aware of any bug related to attribute getting, but there might have been some which is now (with version 2.30.0) solved.
3. Try it in a different browser / OS / architecture. If it works somewhere, you'll know it's an issue of a particular browser / driver / OS / architecture / whatever and you might be able to focus it down and either fix it or [file a bug](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/entry).
4. If you simply want to know whether an element is visible or not, the correct and generally preferred way is to call

   ```java
   element.isDisplayed()
   ```

   This method takes care of all the rules you might need to inspect in order to determine whether it actually is visible or not.
5. If the `style` value changes dynamically on the page (i.e. it's not statically written in the source code of the page), `WebDriver` can't really see it as it doesn't pick up dynamic changes. Try accessing the value via JavaScript:

   ```java
   if (!driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor) {
       throw new IllegalStateException("JavaScript not enabled for this driver!");
   }
   JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   String styleAttribute = (String)js.executeScript("return arguments[0].style", element);
   ```
6. If you actually need to get the computed value of the CSS [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/visibility) attribute that is actually used by the browser and not the one in the `style` atribute (if there either isn't any or is somehow overridden), you need to use the JavaScript's [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) method. One way (described by [this article on quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/getstyles.html)) is this:

   ```js
   var elem = arguments[0];
   if (elem.currentStyle) {
       var vis = elem.currentStyle['visibility'];
   } else {
       var vis = document.defaultView.getComputedStyle(elem, null).getPropertyValue('visibility');
   }
   return vis;
   ```

   Again, this should be invoked via

   ```java
   String visibility = (String)js.executeScript(here_goes_the_whole_script, element);
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help.   

Actually problem was that the visibilty style attribute value becomes visible after i hover on the link, which leads to a pop-up. visibility attribute is defined for this pop up, used super.pause for sometime and I ws able to see all the attributes inline.

Comment: But, I am not sure why the remaninig attribute values are not coming up, as they are still visible in the firebug to me even when the pop-up is not visible