# Appium, Java, iOS: How to find out if element visible, if it's not actually on front

Tags: java, ios, appium-ios

Stuck with defining method for element visibility in UI tests.
My app has few layers that are visible at the same time on screen, and it's hard to find out if element is not visible programatically.

How can i find out if class io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement is visible or not?

I have some attributes from Appium inspector:

```
////////////////////////////////////////
name: 
type: UIATextField
value: 19670027
label: 
hint: 
enabled: true
visible: true
valid: true
location: {446, 375.00003051757812}
size: {196, 56.000007629394531}
xpath://UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAScrollView[2]/UIATextField[6]
////////////////////////////////////////
```

Only thing is changes it's "visible: true", is there any way to get it?
I'm using IOSDriver with appium Java client.
isEnabled, isDisplayed methods don't help as element is present but covered with another layer.

Thanks in advance.
Image: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RIun.png)

Comment: post snip of screen and uiautomator

Comment: See image by link in the end of description.
As you see element is not visible actually but shown in hierarchy so Appium see it.

Answer (score 0):

isDisplayed is supposed to work for the "visible: true/false" attribute.

Only other way that I know of to inspect the "visible" attribute is to take the contents of `driver.getPageSource()` and parse/read the xml to find the correct element and check the attribute value.

Comment: Great idea, thanks!

But anyway it's not an option for such small task.
I guess should be some more obvious and fast way to get 'visible' attribute.
Submitted related issue to appium:
https://github.com/appium/java-client/issues/446

Comment: Found similar issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088832/getattribute-not-returning-complete-value-for-style-in-selenium

Comment: Though element actually display on screen but it's still invisible state in source